# Is a subset of a context free language decidable?

Tags: formal-languages

L is a context free language and J is a subset of L. Is J decidable?
Context free languages are decidables.

Answer (score 0):

Σ<sup>*</sup> is context-free (indeed, it's regular) and it has a lot of subsets.

Answer (score 0):

If L is a context-free language of infinite size, then there are subsets J of L that are decidable, and some that are undecidable. For example, the empty subset is decidable.

To show that there are undecidable subsets, consider the set of all subsets of L. This is an uncountably infinite set since L is an infinite set (in fact, L is countable, but that's irrelevant). But the set of all decidable sets is countable, hence there exist subsets of L that are not decidable.